# Python: Send an Image to a Flask API to be stored on a server for further use

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to send an image to a Flask API. So far, I am using base64 to encode the image to be sent as a string. On the server side, I am receiving that string and decoding it, and attempting to write over a file on the server side. The code runs, but the resulting JPG is not viewable, and it shows "It looks like we don't support this format." I have also attempted saving the file as other photo file formats. It is a jpg that I convert to string so that is why I am saving as jpg.

Here is my client side code:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as img:
    string = base64.b64encode(img.read())

print(type(string))
print(string)

name = 'John Doe'
EmpID = 1
company = 1

def test():
    api_url = "http://192.168.8.13:5000/register-new?emp_name=%s&company_id=%s&emp_id=%s&user_photo=%s" % (name, company, EmpID, string)
    response = requests.post(url= api_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

And here is the server side code for receiving the photo.

```
photo = request.args.get('user_photo')
    photo1 = photo.replace(" ", "")
    f = (base64.b64decode(photo1))
    a = io.BytesIO()
    with open("compare.jpg", "wb") as file:
        file.write(f)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to upload this as base64 data, I suggest putting this as JSON in the post body, rather than as a GET parameter.

On the client side, open the file like this:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as img:
    string = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

Then in your `test` function, take that `image_data` string out of the URL, and use the `request.post` argument `json` to pass this across with the correct Content Type.  You could consider sending the other variables by adding them to the dictionary passed with this arg:

```
def test():
    api_url = "http://192.168.8.13:5000/register-new?emp_name=%s&company_id=%s&emp_id=%s" % (name, company, EmpID)
    response = requests.post(url= api_url, json={'user_photo':string})
```

Then on the backend, grab this with Flask's `request.get_json` function and initialise the `BytesIO` object, before writing the data to that, and finally writing to a file:

```
@app.route('/register-new', methods=['POST'])
def register_new():
    photo = request.get_json()['user_photo']
    
    photo_data = base64.b64decode(photo)
    
    with open("compare.jpg", "wb") as file:
        file.write(photo_data)
```

With a test image this works correctly, as confirmed by the Linux `file` command:

```
$ file compare.jpg
compare.jpg: JPEG image data, baseline, precision 8, 500x750, components 3
```